# Index '[0]' not pulling correct value?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble pulling the `"stoken" value`, I noticed that my script doesn't seem to count those lines for whatever reason just skips over them.  `0` should be `5cd3840` but returns `1` instead. Why is this and what do i need to specify to pull the stolen value?

```
  <form class="search" action="https://www.randomsite.com;" method="get" name="search">
        <div class="searchBox">
            <input type="hidden" name="stoken" value="5CDE3840" />
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cl" value="alist">

              <input type="hidden" name="stoken" value="5CDE3840" />
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="1" />
              <input type="hidden" name="cnid" value="500036" />
<input type="hidden" name="listtype" value="list" />
<input type="hidden" name="actcontrol" value="details" />

              <input type="hidden" name="cl" value="details">
              <input type="hidden" name="aid" value="15763" id="aid">
              <input type="hidden" name="anid" value="15763">
              <input type="hidden" name="parentid" value="15763">
              <input type="hidden" name="panid" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="fnc" value="tobasket">
                        </div>
```

CODE-

```
s = requests.session()
url = "https://www.randomsite.com"
response = s.post(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
inputs = soup.find_all("input",{"type":"hidden"})
stoken = inputs[0]["value"]
cnid = inputs[3]["value"]
aid = inputs[7]["value"]
anid = inputs[8]["value"]
parentid = inputs[9]["value"]
print("STOKEN: ", stoken)
print("CNID: ", cnid)
print("AID: ", aid)
print("ANID: ", anid)
print("PARENTID: ", parentid)
```

output -

```
STOKEN:  1
CNID:  500036
AID:  15763
ANID:  15763
PARENTID:  15763
```

Comment: Is the html you posted the same with  `response.text` in runtime?  I can see here are two `stoken`.

Comment: yeah it  has 2 stoken lines neither seems to count. the html i posted is from me printing soup

Comment: it worked fine for me.  `stoken` is being printed. i used the same code except that i had to save the text in a html file and read it.

Comment: as dumb as this sounds i was printing a post request with soup and not the get i listed above. thank you for your time though, that straightened it all out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'name' attribute to select the relevant tags, ie:

```
stoken = soup.find("input", {"name":"stoken"})['value'] 
cnid = soup.find("input", {"name":"cnid"})['value']  
aid = soup.find("input", {"name":"aid"})['value'] 
anid = soup.find("input", {"name":"anid"})['value'] 
parentid = soup.find("input", {"name":"parentid"})['value']
```

Comment: i like this format much better than i was using above, appreciate it